# Spring Rest Json with JPA entities and DTO's

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jpa

In my Spring boot I have user `@Entity` like:

**User:**

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private boolean enabled = false;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Game> games;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "gameOwner", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Game> gamesOwned;
}
```

In Rest API. I want to create `User` so I've created `UserDto`.

```
public class UserDto {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate birthday;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
}
```

**Question?**

I have `User` entity and DTO class. To create user I use DTO class. To get user I cant use DTO class because it contains less informations than i except. Should I annotate `User` class with `@JsonIgnore`'s or create some another `DTO`?

Comment: What is your question because it is unclear?

Comment: @AlanHay I just edited my question :)

Comment: One option is to avoid DTOs and deal with the entities directlly. Some people would advise against but that is a matter of opinion. You can create an entire REST API with virtually no code using this approach and using the Spring Data and Spring Data Rest modules. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Answer (score 0):

Field `passwordConfirm` is good for DTO class but no entity. In DTO you will match `password` with `passwordConfirm` but in entity class these two field should have the same value, so you don't need two fields for it.

And why you create `UserInfos` class? Why fields from this class cannot be in `User` class? It can be less complicated if you put `UserInfos` fields to `User` class.

Comment: I thought it would be good to separate "details" from "must-be" properties. But now with DTO class it seems actually a bit purposeless.